# error C2248, what is this error and how do I fix it?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, subclass, parent

I'm fairly new to c++ and currently trying to learn templates and how they work. My assignment asks me to create a parent class, base, that takes 4 arguments into a template. As well it must have a subclass that can print the values of the base class.

The parent class gets the values by reading a txt file.

Right now I'm trying to instantiate a subclass so that I can print the values line by line in the parent class.

My code is messy as I am VERY new to c++. My background consists of C#, Java and Javascript. Any help would be fantastic! Thanks in advance.

Error Message:

```
Error   1   error C2248: 'std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ifstream' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>'
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

//template that accept 4 different data types
template<class Type1, class Type2, class Type3, class Type4>
class Base {
    //protected declarations
    protected:
        Type1 str;
        Type2 i;
        Type3 d;
        Type4 b;

    //public declarations
    public:
        int lineRead;
        int data;
        string line, delimiter;
        size_t pos;
        ifstream inputfile;
        string token;

    //public functions
    public:
        void readFile(int lineNum) {
            //temp information holders
            lineRead = 0;
            pos = 0;
            delimiter = " ";

            //open .txt file
            inputfile.open("file.txt");

            //while end of file is not reached
            while (!inputfile.eof()) {
                //increment line counter
                lineRead++;

                //read line
                getline(inputfile,line);

                //if this is the line requested fill the template members with the
                //correct data. <string, int, double, bool>
                if(lineNum == lineRead){
                    //getting the string
                    pos = line.find(delimiter);
                    token = line.substr(0, pos);
                    str = token;
                    line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());

                    //getting the integer
                    pos = line.find(delimiter);
                    token = line.substr(0, pos);
                    i = stoi(token);
                    line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());

                    //getting the double
                    pos = line.find(delimiter);
                    token = line.substr(0, pos);
                    d = stod(token);
                    line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());

                    //getting the boolean
                    pos = line.find(delimiter);
                    token = line.substr(0, pos);
                    b = to_bool(token);
                    line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
                }
            }

            //close the file
            inputfile.close();
            system("pause");
        };

        //Changes a string to lower case and then reads the string
        //to find if the value is true or false. Returns a boolean.
        bool to_bool(string str) {
            transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
            istringstream is(str);
            bool tempB;
            is >> boolalpha >> tempB;
            return tempB;
        }
};

class Subclass : public Base<string, int, double, bool> {
    private:
        string name;

    public:
        Subclass::Subclass(string name) {
            cout << "test";
        }

        void printValues() {
            cout << str;
        }


};

//main function
int main() {
    //call Base class and give the template data types
    Subclass b = Subclass("test");

    //read the file
    b.readFile(2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Subclass b = Subclass("test");
```

This creates an object, and then tries to copy it. Your class is not copyable, hence the error (also, copying derived classes is [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/509868) in its own way). To create an object without copying, use the following syntax:

```
Subclass b("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an `std::ifstream` as a member, but they're non-copyable, hence hte error message you cited. Pre-C++11, the idiomatic way to make something non-copyable was to declare its copy constructor with a private access specifier (which is what you're seeing), so that nobody could accidentally use it. In C++11, the `delete` keyword is preferred and you'll get an error along the lines of "use of deleted function".

You should either:

1. Define a copy constructor and copy assignment operator
2. Not have a non-copyable member

I would go with (2) if I were you; ask yourself why you need this as a member and then find a way to factor it out.